# How to change array shape of list array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, reshape

I have (808,1,22,2000) list array which load from json file.
It has 808 number of (22,2000) arrays.
so i want to make this to (22,2000,808).
Can you let me know how to do it?

Comment: Could you add some sample data, and some examples of what you want out of it?

Comment: oh. First, (808,1) shape of list, and each row has (22,2000) array. so when i 'np.shape(data)' then it shows (808,1,22,2000). so i want to change it to (22,2000,808).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is an ambiguity here because it's not clear why you want to change the shape, if I'm right, `numpy.reshape` should be your answer.
Look at this example:

```
>> a = np.array([[[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]],[[[8,9,10,11],[12,13,14,15]]],[[[16,17,18,19],[20,21,22,23]]]])
>> a
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
     [ 4,  5,  6,  7]]],

   [[[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
     [12, 13, 14, 15]]],

   [[[16, 17, 18, 19],
     [20, 21, 22, 23]]]])

>> a.shape
(3, 1, 2, 4)

>> b = a.reshape((a.shape[2],a.shape[3],a.shape[0]))
>> b
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5],
    [ 6,  7,  8],
    [ 9, 10, 11]],

   [[12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17],
    [18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23]]])

>> b.shape
(2, 4, 3)
```